Can you freeze a turkey/chicken in brine to help absorb more brine into the bird
I was wondering if anyone has a theory on this: If you freeze a bird in brine for a few days then thaw will it absorb more liquid and flavor?
I've heard that freezing causes cell walls to expand and I'm thinking that as it thaws the brine will be absorbed into the meat at a higher ratio. Is there reliable science behind this?

Getting "more brine" into a protein is probably unnecessary, unless you are looking for an inedible product.  If you want precision, just use equilibrium brining.  Calculate the weight of food + water.  Calculate the amount of salt needed (usually 1 - 2%).  Mix the salt and water to create brine. Leave protein in brine in the refrigerator.  This might take longer than a high concentration brine, but the system will equilibrate and you will not over-salt. Maybe 3 - 5 days for a 15 pound turkey, for example. If you want more than 2% (unlikely), just calculate a higher salt concentration and wait. If you want to brine more quickly create a 5-8% brine and remove the 15 pound turkey in no more than 18 hours.
Brining is only about getting salt into the protein.  Other flavors are likely just a surface treatment, as those flavor molecules are much larger and don't penetrate nearly as far.
Freezing delays the process, likely negatively impacts the final texture, and is unnecessary.


i've heard that freezing causes cell walls to expand

Meat doesn't have cell walls, only cell membranes. But yes, at that temperature, water expands as it cools. So the cell membranes (which are somewhat elastic) will expand slightly as the water-based intracellular fluid they hold expands.

i'm thinking that as it thaws the brine will be absorbed into the meat at a higher ratio.

I'm not sure why you would expect this. As the water warms it will contract, and the cell membranes will return to their original size. None of that involves absorption.

there's so much science in cooking that i wanted opinions from you educated people. it was just a thought as i'm going to smoke a turkey this weekend
